# ASP.net Stopping a Repeater

Tags: c#, repeater, nested-repeater

I have a series of nested repeaters; for this example, assume 3.  I'm binding the inner repeaters using the ItemDataBound event.

I want the 2 outside repeaters to display their assigned repeater stuff.  Then I want the 3rd and inner most repeater to simply output some message if there is data that COULD be repeated.

So to reiterate: I want two repeaters to repeat, and the third to tell me if there is stuff to repeat.

I do no not need to actually use a repeater for the inner most, if a label or some other element better accomplishes what I'm trying to do excellent.

Answer (score 1):

So, on the ItemDataBound of the 2nd repeater, where you would normally assigned data to the 3rd repeater, can you not just look at the data, decide if it has more than 1 record, and set a label appropriately?